# GAN implementation on leaf dataset

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan, google-generativeai

Basically, I want to generate leaf images with the help of GAN architecture. I have a small dataset of leaf images with various classes of diseases. So when I am searching for the code, I am only getting code related to MNIST dataset but I want related to leaves. So anyone can provide any github repo, youtube video or any code so that I can proceed with it.

I did try applying the different code but it didn't work out for leaf images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.